# Using multiple folders per project in Visual Studio 2008

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

I would like to know how to have multiple folders per project in Visual Studio.  Of course namespaces and DLLs have to be the same when the solution is built with or without using multiple folders.

I tend to be forgetful at things especially this one and forgot to bookmark the link.  As far as I know it is an answer in SO.  I looked at the question Visual Studio Hidden Features, but I can't find it.  The SO answer link or the direct link to the site outside SO, is very much accepted and appreciated.

Comment: I don't know if you realized, but I removed the "hidden-features" tag and the "thanks" in your text for a reason. This is not a hidden feature (not very well hidden if you can right-click in Solution Explorer and see the command), and the SO Community has decided against salutations, other extraneous text in questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a new folder by right-clicking in Solution Explorer and using the Add, New Folder menu command.

It is a common practice for folder names correspond to namespaces. For example, if you create a folder named `WebPages`, use a `namespace Webpages` block in the source files that you put in that folder.